# Достать определённый параметр из JSON с помощью requests

Tags: python, requests

В чём суть задачи. Есть апи со списком проектов. Проекты в формате json содержат id, название и ещё некоторые параметры. Сейчас есть код, который выводит весь список проектов из этого апи, то есть получается, что выводится что-то навроде

> {'start_date': '2000-01-01', 'end_date': '2000-01-01', 'id': 66,
>   'title': '3', 'created': '2018-11-07T08:09:56.633540Z'}.

Код выглядит следующим образом, как обычный пример работы с requests:

```
s = requests.get('url')
data = s.json()
print(data)
```

Так вот, подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом из всего списка проектов мне вывести только содержимое параметров title по каждому из проектов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('\n'.join(i['title'] for i in data))
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Однако, мне же нужно нужно дать понять коду, что "title" относится к json, так ведь?

Comment: @rolkins что значит "дать понять коду, что 'title' относится к json"?

Comment: Нет, уже всё. Просто сперва [title] был без кавычек и меня это смутило, но теперь всё хорошо.
Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: @rolkins [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).